# How to remove frequent/infrequent features from Sklearn CountVectorizer?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

Is it possible to remove a percentage of features that occur most frequently / infrequently, from the CountVectorizer?

So basically organize the features from a greatest to least occurrence distribution and just remove a percentage from the left or right side?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no straight forward way to do that.
Let me propose a way to achieve the result you want.
I will assume that you are only interested in unigrams (one-word features) to make the examples also simpler.

---

Regarding the top-x per cent of the features, a possible implementation can be based on the max_features parameter of the CountVectorizer (see [user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)).
First, you would need to find out the total number of features by using the CountVectorizer with the default values so that it generates the full vocabulary of terms in the corpus.

```
vect = CountVectorizer()
bow = vect.fit_transform(corpus)
total_features = len(vect.vocabulary_)
```

Then you use the CountVectorizer with the max_features parameter, limiting the number of features to the top percentage you need, say 20%. When using the max_features the most frequent terms are selected automatically.

```
top_vect = CountVectorizer(max_features=int(total_features * 0.2))
top_bow = top_vect.fit_transform(corpus)
```

---

Now, regarding the bottom-x per cent of the features, even though I cannot think a good reason why you need that, here is an approach. The vocabulary parameter can be used to limit the model to count only the less frequent terms. For that, we use the output of the first run of the CountVectorizer to create a list of the less common terms.

```
# Create a list of (term, frequency) tuples sorted by their frequency
sum_words = bow.sum(axis=0) 
words_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in vect.vocabulary_.items()]
words_freq = sorted(words_freq, key = lambda x: x[1])

# Keep only the terms in a list
vocabulary, _ = zip(*words_freq[:int(total_features * 0.2)])
vocabulary = list(vocabulary)
```

Finally, we use the vocabulary to limit the model to the less frequent terms.

```
bottom_vect = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocabulary)
bottom_bow = bottom_vect.fit_transform(corpus)
```